# How can I implement my anagram and palindrome functions to check the words input by a user?

Tags: c, function, logic, palindrome, anagram

I got some help earlier fixing up one of the functions I am using in this program, but now I'm at a loss of logic.

I have three purposes and two functions in this program. The first purpose is to print a sentence that the user inputs backwards. The second purpose is to check if any of the words are anagrams with another in the sentence. The third purpose is to check if any one word is a palindrome.

I successfully completed the first purpose. I can print sentences backwards. But now I am unsure of how I should implement my functions to check whether or not any words are anagrams or palindromes.

Here's the code;

```
/*
 * Ch8pp14.c
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 12, 2013
 *      Author: RivalDog
 *      Purpose: Reverse a sentence, check for anagrams and palindromes
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> //Included ctype for tolower / toupper functions
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0

//Write boolean function that will check if a word is an anagram
bool check_anagram(char a[], char b[])
{
   int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, c = 0;
// Convert arrays into all lower case letters
   while(a[c])
   {
       a[c] = (tolower(a[c]));
       c++;
   }

   c = 0;

   while(b[c])
      {
       b[c] = (tolower(b[c]));
       c++;
      }

      c = 0;

   while (a[c] != 0)
   {
      first[a[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }

   c = 0;

   while (b[c] != 0)
   {
      second[b[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      if (first[c] != second[c])
         return false;
   }

   return true;
}

//Write boolean function that will check if a word is a palindrome
bool palindrome(char a[])
{
    int c=0, j, k;
    //Convert array into all lower case letters
    while (a[c])
    {
        a[c] = (tolower(a[c]));
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = strlen(a) - 1;
    while (j < k)
    {
        if(a[j++] != a[k--])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char a[80], terminator;
    //Prompt user to enter sentence, store it into an array
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    j = getchar();
    while (i < 80)
    {
        a[i] = j;
        ++i;
        j = getchar();
        if (j == '!' || j == '.' || j == '?')
        {
            terminator = j;
            break;
        }
        else if(j == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while(a[k])
    {
        a[k] = (tolower(a[k]));
        k++;
    }
    k = 0;
    while(k < i)
    {
        printf("%c", a[k]);
        k++;
    }
    printf("%c\n", terminator);
    //Search backwards through the loop for the start of the last word
    //print the word, and then repeat that process for the rest of the words
    for(j = i; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        while(j > -1)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                for(k=j;k<i;k++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", a[k]);
                    }
                printf("%c", terminator);
                    break;
            }
            else if (a[j] != ' ')
                --j;
            else if (a[j] == ' ')
                {
                    for(k=j+1;k<i;k++)
                        {
                            printf("%c", a[k]);
                        }
                    printf(" ");
                        break;
                }
        }
        i = j;
    }
    //Check if the words are anagrams using previously written function
    for( i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == ' ')
        {

        }
    }

    //Check if the words are palindromes using previously written function

return 0;
}
```

I was thinking that perhaps I could again search through the array for the words by checking if the element is a space, and if it is, store from where the search started to the space's index-1 in a new array, repeat that process for the entire sentence, and then call my functions on all of the arrays. The issue I am seeing is that I can't really predict how many words a user will input in a sentence... So how can I set up my code to where I can check for anagrams/palindromes?

Thank you everyone!

~RivalDog

Comment: may be better suits for [Code-Review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Your code is hard to read. You should have used higher level functions such as scanf() or fgets(), and especially strtok(). Writing a sentence backwards is very easy if you use strtok(). I won't blame you, but if you didn't know about strtok(), now you do. I highly recommend you to use it. With this code, I doubt anyone will take the time to understand it and help you.

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17130789/2455888). You will get some idea how to calculate number of words in a string.

Comment: I think, that it is not a good idea to change content of arguments of check_anagram... please don't write functions with side effects...

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Scanf didn't work for what I wanted to do, and I've never heard of or used fgets() or strtok(). I can't use it since I don't know what it does. And personally, I don't feel my code is hard to read at all, and I'm a novice. I've got a good number of comments explaining what's going on in the portion of code where I need help.

Comment: @haccks I read it, and now I think I can calculate the number of words in a string, but this still makes the anagram check difficult... let's say I have 4 words in a sentence. I need to compare the first word to the second, third, and fourth words, then compare the second word to the third and fourth words, and then the third and fourth word still need to be compared together. Imagine a sentence with 10 words. That's a lot of comparisons to do...

I did a little research on the strtok() function, and it seems that might be very useful in checking for anagrams and palindromes... I think...

Comment: @V-X It doesn't change the arguments outside the scope of the function. It only converts the arguments into lower case while they exist inside that function. But since you pointed that out, I remember that I converted the array into all lower case in the main function, so I can get rid of this piece of code from my anagram function.

Comment: Strings as arrays are passed as a pointer, not by value. There is nothing like local copy of the arguments inside the function.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I posted the question there and they said it's off topic since I was asking for code to be written, there is no code to actually review. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @V-X Right, I forgot about that... Well, I did fix it. I change the array to lower case in the main function now, so no need for any of my  functions to do so.

Comment: @RivalDog; For anagram no need to check number of words.I am posting my code fro anagram. Take a look.

Comment: @RivalDog Hmm ok!, Did you get your answer? let me know if I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better,if you first optimize your code and make it readable by adding comments.Then you can divide the problem in smaller parts like
1.How to count words in a string?
2.How to check whether two words are anagrams?
3.How to check whether a word is palindrome or not?
And these smaller programs you could easily get by Googling. Then your job will be just to integrate these answers. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already figured out how to check for anagrams and palindromes. There are comments in the code that explain that. So according to your comment, all I've got left to do is count the number of words in a string, but that is incorrect. There is more to do than that. Once I've counted the number of words in the string, how can I send in all possible pairs of words through my anagram function, and how can I send each individual word through my palindrome function?

Comment: Then u can use some kind of hashing for words where each word computes to some unique hash value and store those values in some array. Then if you come across a word then u need to compute the hash value of the word and search in the array for anagram purpose. eg. the word 'abcd' hash can be computed as 2*3*5*7, The multiplication of first four prime numbers.I mean u could assign one prime number for each character. U need to figure out first 26 prime numbers. Now any combination of 'abcd' would always give the product as 3*5*7*11. Or you can think of some better hash function by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To check anagram, no need to calculate number of words and comparing them one by one or whatever you are thinking.
Look at this code. In this code function `read_word()` is reading word/phrase input using an `int` array of 26 elements to keep track of how many times each letter has been seen instead of storing the letters itself. Another function `equal_array()` is to check whether both array `a` and `b` (in `main`) are equal (anagram) or not and return a Boolean value as a result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void read_word(int counts[26]);
bool equal_array(int counts1[26],int counts2[26]);

int main()
{
    int a[26] = {0}, b[26] = {0};

    printf("Enter first word/phrase: ");
    read_word(a);
    printf("Enter second word/phrase: ");
    read_word(b);

    bool flag = equal_array(a,b);
    printf("The words/phrase are ");
    if(flag)
        printf("anagrams");
    else
        printf("not anagrams"); 

    return 0;
}

void read_word(int counts[26])
{
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' || ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        counts[toupper(ch) - 'A']++;
}

bool equal_array(int counts1[26],int counts2[26])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 26)
    {
        if(counts1[i] == counts2[i])
            i++;
        else
            break;  
    }

    return i == 26 ? true : false;  
}
```