# Average Word Length [C]

Tags: c

I don't see where my logic is flawed in the code, for some reason it adds 1 to `i` even when ch isn't equal to 32.

```
int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    float i, j;

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    for (i = 1, j = 0;;)
    {
        ch = getchar();

        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
            break;

        if (ch != 32)
            j++;

        if (ch = 32)
            i++;
    }

    printf("Average word length: %.2f", j/i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace `=` with `==`. Done.

Comment: one way to help avoid this error is to always say `32 == ch` instead of how you have it.  Then, if you forget one `=`, there will be an error or warning, since you can't assign the value of `ch` to 32

Comment: A proper compiler, with proper compiler settings, would have pointed out this error.

Comment: @FCo: Rather use correct compiler settings, for instance with gcc, -Wall and -Werror, this will generate a compile time error.

Comment: @Étienne yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

`if (ch = 32)` is problem since you are setting ch to 32. You should instead use equals operator `if (ch == 32)`

Also similar question has been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128722/average-word-length-for-a-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

To compare you must use `==` instead of `=`. You're setting `ch` to 32 at this point, so the return value is always true.

Comment: Did it fix your problem?