# explain the logic behind the structure of code needed to account for extra spaces, in order to calculate the correct average word length

Tags: c

This is the question on my assignment: Write a program that prompts the user to enter a sentence (assume that a sentence can have a maximum of 50 characters). It then counts the vowels and consonants in it. It also calculates the average word length of the input sentence. Word length is the total number of alphabetic characters in the sentence divided by the total number of words in it. Words are separated by one or more spaces. All the results are displayed at the end.

So far I have been able to complete all aspects of the question but I am running into a logical error on my part. When the user inputs more than a normal amount of spaces, it messes up the answer given for average word length.

Here is my code calculating average word length:

```
for(i = 1; sent[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if( sent[i] == ' '){
        ++spaceCount;
    }
    else if((sent[i] != ' ') && (sent[i] != '\n')){
        ++charCount;
    }
}

avgWordLength = (charCount / (spaceCount+1)) ;
```

Could someone help explain the logic behind the structure of code needed to account for extra spaces, in order to calculate the correct average word length

Here is a link to a previously already answered question: 
[Average word length for a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128722/average-word-length-for-a-sentence)

But my school has not taught the "getchar" function yet and I would not like to use it unless I have too. To be more clear, is there away to complete the question without using the "getchar" function?

Here is an example of the problem when compiling and running

```
// Everything works good when
string: Thursday is ok 
Average word length: 4.00 characters

// this is where my code fall apart 
string:     Thursday is ok
Average word length: 1.86 characters
```

Comment: To count number of words: if the current character is a space and the next character (warning: don't forget to check for boundary) is not a space -> wordCount++. Also: https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalnum

Comment: And by "boundary" mentioned by @zerkms the first character may be a space or not as well as the last character.

Comment: @MFisherKDX in that case I meant the string boundary - the `\0` or whatever is used as a string boundary (say, in case if it's stored in a fixed size array). Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Note: `for` loop has `for(i = 1; sent[i] != '\0'; i++){`.  The later `&& (sent[i] != '\0')` is always true.

Comment: in the process of using what you guys have said, working through the problem. I will post when finished or stuck

Comment: now i have it all working, except when i have 2 or more spaces in between words. created a new problem...

Comment: I have figured it all out now, see marked answer for my explanation on how I did it. Thanks again everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you think about it, what you want to do is just treat any uninterrupted series of *whitepace* characters as one for the purpose of computing the word count. You can include `ctype.h` and use the `isspace` function to test all possible whitespace characters, or if you are supposed to do it manually, then at least check for `space` or `tab` characters (e.g. you could have a mixed sequence of spaces and tabs that should still be counted as a single (e.g. `" \t   \t  "`)

To handle multiple whitespace characters and count the sequence as one, just set a *flag* (e.g. `ws` for whitespace) and only increment `spaceCount` when you encounter the first whitespace, and reset the flag if another non-whitespace character is encountered.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something like the following:

```
int ws = 0;     /* flag to treat multiple whitespace as 1 */

for(i = 0; sent[i]; i++){
    if (sent[i] == ' ' || sent[i] == '\t') {
        if (!ws) {
            spaceCount++;
            ws = 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        charCount++;  /* non-whitespace character count */
        ws = 0;
    }
}
```

(**note:** begin your check at `i = 0` to protect against *Undefined Behavior* in the event `sent` is the *empty-string*.)

(**note2:** you can check `charCount` before setting your first `spaceCount` and check `ws` after leaving the loop to handle *leading* and *trailing* whitespace -- and adjust `spaceCount` as necessary. That is left as an exercise)

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I have followed the logic behind your code involving white space and come to the conclusion that the perimeters for space counting should be                   (charCount > 0) && (sent[i] == ' ') && (sent[i + 1] != ' ') && (sent[i +1] != '\n')  By doing this the question works perfectly now

Comment: To make things clear, the previously posted parameters are used when incrementing the spaceCount variable

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone help explain the logic behind the structure of code needed to account for extra spaces, in order to calculate the correct average word length

You could use a state machine. You have two states:

1) Looking for the end of a word.

2) Looking for the end of a space sequence.

Look at the first character in the sentence. It is either the beginning of a word or a space. This tells you if you are in state 1 or 2.

If in state 1, then look for a space or the end of the sentence. If you find a space, set your state to 2.

If in state 2, then look for a non-space or the end of the sentence. If you find a non-space then set your state to 1.

Answer (score 0):

> counts the vowels and consonants in it. It also calculates the average word length of the input sentence.
>
> Could someone help explain the logic behind the structure of code needed to account for extra spaces

There really is no need to count spaces.  Instead all that is needed to to count the number of times a letter begins a word - it followed a non-letter - or was first character.

```
// pseudo code
sentence_stats(const char *s) {
  vowels = 0; 
  consonants = 0; 
  word_count = 0;
  
  previous = 0;
  while (*s) {
    if (isletter(*s)) {  // OP to make isletter(), isvowel()
      if (!isletter(previous)) {
        word_count++; // start of word
      }
      if (isvowel(*s)) vowels++;
      else consonants++;
    } else if (*s == ' ') {
       ; // nothing to do
    } else  {
       TBD_CODE_Handle_non_letter_non_space();
    }
    previous = *s;
    s++;
  }
  average = (vowels + consonants)/word_count
}
```